# Do Objects share their Methods or do they have their own ones

Tags: php, oop, memory, prototypal-inheritance

When i instantiate multiple Objects in PHP will each Object has his own Method or will only 1 Method be instantiated ?

Example:

```
Class SimpleClass {
 public $attr = 'some value';
 public function set_attr($val){
  $this->attr = $val ;
 }
}

$sc1 = new SimpleClass(); 
$sc2 = new SimpleClass();
$sc1->set_attr('new value1');
$sc2->set_attr('new value2');
```

In this Example i want to know if each SimpleClass Object has its own method set_attr() in Memory or if there is only one. In JavaScript it is possible to do it this way with the prototype Object. And i want To know if it is in other Languages also like that.

Just for clarification :
In JavaScript i can create an Method based on the prototype Object :

```
SimpleClass = function() { this.attr = 'old val'; };
SimpleClass.prototype.set_attr = function(val) { this.attr = val ; };

var sc1 = new SimpleClass();
var sc2 = new SimpleClass();

sc1.set_attr('new val');
sc2.set_attr('new val');
```

In this Example there will be an variable assigend to each Object, sc1 and sc2 but just 1 method ( set_attr() ) will be assigend to the SimpleClass prototype Object.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Prototypal inheritance in PHP (like in JavaScript)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2192049/prototypal-inheritance-in-php-like-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes there will be only 1 method total.

However, creating methods in a constructor or a method is possible in at least in Javascript, PHP and C#. Doing
so is sometimes seen in Javascript but I have never heard of it being done in PHP or C#.

In the following examples, all create function identities needlessly and waste memory.

In PHP

```
<?php
class WastingMemoryForMethods {
    public $value = 3;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->method1 = function() {
            return $this->value;        
        };

        $this->method2 = function() {

        };

        $this->method3 = function() {

        };
    }
}
$a = new WastingMemoryForMethods();
echo $a->method1->__invoke();
//3
```

In Javascript:

```
function WastingMemoryForMethods() {
    this.value = 3;

    this.method1 = function() {
        return this.value;
    };

    this.method2 = function() {

    };

    this.method3 = function() {

    };
}

var a = new WastingMemoryForMethods();
console.log(a.method1());
//3
```

In C#

```
class WastingMemoryForMethods {
    public int value = 3;

    public Func<int> method1;
    public Func<int> method2;
    public Func<int> method3;

    public WastingMemoryForMethods() {
        this.method1 = () => this.value;
        this.method2 = () => 0;
        this.method3 = () => 0;
    }

    public static void Main(string[] args) {
        var a = new WastingMemoryForMethods();
        Console.WriteLine(a.method1());
        //3
    }
}
```

Comment: Okay, that was what i was thinking too. I had no proof that it is like that in every other language.

Answer (score 1):

Only one method will be instantiated.  It will be called with an implicit this pointer to the object you called it on.


http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php

Comment: I get a 404 on that link.

Answer (score 1):

There will be one class with all of it's methods in memory, there will then be three separate instantiations of the SimpleClass class. $sc1, $sc2, and $sc3 will each have their own copies of the set_attr method. Calling one will not affect another. I believe they call through to the class object in memory and it's methods but operate independently.

To create one instantiation that has a pointer, you can clone or copy the instantiation:

```
$sc1 = new SimpleClass();
$sc2 = $sc1;
$sc2->set_attr('something');
$sc1->get_attr(); // would return 'something' as $sc2 is a pointer to $sc1
```

Comment: In javascript, the prototype chain is for extending objects. To have a more analogous answer-

    class ComplexClass extends SimpleClass{}

    $sc4 = new ComplexClass();
    $sc4->set_attr('something');

-would be similar. If you add a method to SimpleClass, it will be available to ComplexClass. Upon instantiation though, each object is its own encapsulation and can no longer be extended.

Comment: This is totally incorrect, why would they have their own copies of the method?

Comment: I should have said scopes rather than copies. $this keeps the instantiations separate so that calling a method on one does not change the parameters of the other or the original class.

Comment: The way it should be thought about is that `set_attr` is a normal function with extra hidden parameter for the `$this`, and `$sc1->get_attr()` then effectively calls that function `get_attr($sc1)`. There is no need to create separate scopes or any copies or even think of it as something different from normal function.